# images in phpmyadmin using image path

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, phpmyadmin

Im trying to add images to my database by using an image path, under the Image column, i have used varchar as the the type and i have inserted images/canin.jpg as the value.

When im trying to display this image using php it doesn't work, this is what i have :

```
        $sql = "SELECT dog_id, dogbreed, image, sellercontact, location FROM dog";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Dog Breed</th><th>Image</th><th>Seller and Contact number</th><th>Location</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["dog_id"]."</td><td>".$row["dogbreed"]." <td>".$row["image"]."</td><td>".$row["sellercontact"]." </td><td>".$row["location"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
```

All the other information such as dog it, dog breed etc is being retrieved, but its not bringing back the image.

any ideas?

Comment: is it just returning `images/canin.jpg` or is that cell blank?

Comment: i have created a folder called images with that file name in it. the images file is located along with all my source code etc

Comment: But is it just showing the path instead of the actual image? or is it entirely blank

Comment: yeah it is just showing the path

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HTML [`img`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) tag to display the image.

Replace `<td>".$row["image"]."</td>` with `<td><img src=\"".$row["image"]."\"/></td>`

This should produce `<td><img="images/canin.jpg"/></td>` when executed

Comment: What markup is being output if you view the source?

Comment: yay it worked!! :) i must have left a bit of it out when pasting it over!

Comment: @lauren Don't forget to mark as the answer, by clicking the tick mark next to my answer, if it helped.